# mysql insert multiple rows in one query with a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

When I try this code it shows me an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `notifications` (title,date,group_id,owner_id) VALUES ('Een nie' at line 1

```
$date = time();
$gid = 123;
$q = "INSERT INTO `notifications` (title,date,group_id,owner_id) VALUES ";

$zw = mysqli_query($database->connection,"SELECT `owner_id` FROM `joins` WHERE `group_id` = '$gid'");
$ch = mysqli_num_rows($zw);
while($gg = mysqli_fetch_array($zw))
{
  $owner_idd = $gg['owner_id'];
  $q .= "('xxxxxEen nieuwe aanbieding voor groep     $gid','$date','$gid','$owner_idd'),";
}

$q .= rtrim($q,',');


mysqli_query($database->connection, $q) or die (mysqli_error($database->connection));
```

Where is the error?

Comment: It expects values like that `INSERT INTO `notifications` (title,date,group_id,owner_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?)`

Comment: first echo your query and see what output you get.

Comment: $q .= "('xxxxxEen nieuwe aanbieding voor groep     {$gid}','$date','$gid','$owner_idd'),";  i had made correction please check it

Comment: When echo the output i get this: INSERT INTO `notifications` (title,date,group_id,owner_id) VALUES ('xxxxxEen nieuwe aanbieding voor groep 17','1469531826','17','1'),('xxxxxEen nieuwe aanbieding voor groep 17','1469531826','17','2'),INSERT INTO `notifications` (title,date,group_id,owner_id) VALUES ('xxxxxEen nieuwe aanbieding voor groep 17','1469531826','17','1'),('xxxxxEen nieuwe aanbieding voor groep 17','1469531826','17','2')Y

Answer (score 0):

Try that (using PDO you can change it to mysqli_):

**index.php**

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
        ));
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$date = time();
$gid = 2;
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM joins WHERE `group_id` = '$gid'");
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$values = array();
if (count($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $dataIndex => $dataValue) {
        $values[] = "('title','$date'," . implode(",", array_values($dataValue)) . ")";
    }
    $values = implode(",", $values);
    $insert = "INSERT INTO notifications (title,date,group_id,owner_id) VALUES $values";
    $sth = $pdo->prepare($insert);
    $sth->execute();
}
```

**notifications table create:**

```
CREATE TABLE `notifications` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `owner_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**joins table create:**

```
CREATE TABLE `joins` (
    `group_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `owner_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `group_id` (`group_id`),
    INDEX `owner_id` (`owner_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your mysql query error message "'INSERT INTO notifications (title,date,group_id,owner_id) VALUES ('Een nie' at line 1"
single quote creating problem.

try to add mysqli_real_escape_string($con,"dd'sdfsdfsdf") before pushing the data into insert query.